# where does the welcome message of interactive python interpreter come from?

Tags: python

When entering `python` on Linux shell, the welcome message is printed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

where do those lines come from? Are they determined during compilation or installation?

I have another version of `python` executable and a set of libs on my system, but when I enter that `python`, it also shows the same welcome message as above.

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

I use absolute path to start another version of python. And just found the welcome message has the same content as sys.version and sys.platform. But if I copy the other version of python to a different Linux machine B, and still use absolute path to run it. I get

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

This welcome message is the same as machine B's python.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. Not the most fantastically interesting, maybe, but I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Half of it will be due to your `PATH` as to which version of python you are calling. Is your question less about what generates that output and more about how to invoke a particular python interpreter?

Comment: did you check if "when you enter the other one" you arenot actually calling the same one - due to pathing, symlinks or whatever?#

Comment: @roganjosh  and patrick artner,  I just updated. I used absolute path to run the other python.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: The C version source code is similar:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e4db2f253c555568d56177c2fd083bcf8f88d34/Modules/main.c#L705

```
if (!Py_QuietFlag && (Py_VerboseFlag ||
                    (command == NULL && filename == NULL &&
                     module == NULL && stdin_is_interactive))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Python %s on %s\n",
        Py_GetVersion(), Py_GetPlatform());
    if (!Py_NoSiteFlag)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", COPYRIGHT);
}
```

which `Py_GetVersion()` returns version base on a MACRO

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e4db2f253c555568d56177c2fd083bcf8f88d34/Include/patchlevel.h#L26

```
/* Version as a string */
#define PY_VERSION          "3.7.0a0"
```

so it is compile time determined, you probably have a messed up PATH?

---

Old answer, which is actually just a python module

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e4db2f253c555568d56177c2fd083bcf8f88d34/Lib/code.py#L214

```
    if banner is None:
        self.write("Python %s on %s\n%s\n(%s)\n" %
                   (sys.version, sys.platform, cprt,
                    self.__class__.__name__))
    elif banner:
        self.write("%s\n" % str(banner))
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but still fun to know.

Comment: That's the `code` module, not the actual implementation of interactive mode, though.

Comment: You're looking at the C now, but the wrong part of the C. What you're looking at is part of the handling for `python --version`, not the interactive header.

Comment: well screw me, updated again Lol... Hope I get it right this time

Comment: @user2357112 I'm curious why you're not answering this one?

Comment: @roganjosh: I've got most of an answer written up, but the newest revision of this answer is finally using the right source code, so I didn't bother posting it.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the reason. The second `python` binary loads .so files in startup, and it loads libpython as follows:

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f087cf58000)
```

This is the same as my system `python`. After setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the lib directory of the second `python`, I can see the correct welcome message.